# WCF using ClientBase<T> slow on first access

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF client/server, the client proxy is using `ClientBase<T>`.  When accessing the client proxy the first call to any service takes ~8 seconds.  Subsequent calls (inside a 15 second timeout) take ~0.5 seconds.  I found the following article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/11/why-does-wcf-become-slow-after-being-idle-for-15-seconds.aspx

Firstly there is a comment to suggest this is fixed in .net 4.5 (I am using 4.5.1 yet i still face this issue).  I have tried putting the suggested workaround in place but still have this issue.

My client proxy code:

```
public class MyClient : ClientBase<IMyBrowser>, IMyBrowser
{
    private MyClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : base(binding, remoteAddress) { }

    public string GetCustomerCommissionGroup(string customerId)
    {
        string _result = null;
        try
        {
            _result = Channel.GetCustomerCommissionGroup(customerId);
        }
        catch (FaultException<MyFault> _fault)
        {
          // do something
        }
        return _result;
    }
}
```

Client config:

```
<system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpNone">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>

  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="StandardBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpNone" contract="MyBrowser">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:23456/MyService.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="StandardBehaviour">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

</system.serviceModel>
```

I am hosting this in a windows service application, using Net.Tcp and have no security in place.

EDIT:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/26/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared.aspx

Thought this was the solution, but sadly the long startup still remains

EDIT2:

I decided to revise my solution to use WebAPI over WCF.  I currently still have a lag on startup (~2 seconds) but am getting better logging and actually simpler control versus WCF.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article which referred to NetBios as being a potential cause.  I disabled this service and WINS and LMHosts lookup on my hosting server, timeout reduced from ~8 seconds to ~3.5. Winning!

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/114132/WCF-First-Call-Slow